# Prebuilt datetimev2 entity in Spanish not trigger by

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Im using LUIS, to detect intents in some chatbot.

If the text input have "... esta semana" (this week) they match correctly, but if the text say **"... la semana pasada"** (last week) the entity are not detected.

Are some way to improve the datetimev2 pattern?

Comment: Please consider logging this issue on the github repo -- https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text

Answer (score 0):

We've filed a new issue in the [Recognizers-Text repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/issues/556). You can track the issue there.